# Which method to get this smoother transition between two shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, transitions

I am learning Adobe Illustrator and I am trying to understand how to get that smoother transition between the shape and the line. So far my attempts have been unsuccessful. The curves are still to clear and unbalanced and so is the transition. Can I get it just by using the pen tool or is there some grid system plus shape builder tool involved here?

Examples:

[image: Fig.1]

[image: Fig.2]

My attempts:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It simply takes practice and familiarity with how Bezier curves and their handles will create artwork. [PenTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPh5D.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Illustrator CC's Rounded Corner Widget functionality.

Draw a shape without curves, then select only the corner widgets you want to round by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+clicking them to make a multiple selection, then click and drag them to make the curves.

Example

[image]Example

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, a boa constrictor digesting an elephant.

Comment: @Wolff exactly!  LOL